# Django, jQuery. I can't load() after the same div multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I am trying to let the user create multiple types of the same input form.

The problem is that the first time I click on the button a form is appended to the `append_form` div, but no matter how many more times I click on the "Add" button, no other form is appended. What am I doing wrong?

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-9"><strong>{% trans "Please, add as many measures as you like to be available for the institutional simulation" %}</strong></div>
<div class="col-md-3"><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="addForm('{% url "add_measure_form" %}')"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> {% trans "Add Measure" %} </button></div>

<div id="append_forms"></div>
```

And this is my script

```
function addForm(url){
    $("#append_forms").after().load(url);
}
```

And this is my django views:

```
def add_measure_form(request):
    data = {

    }
    return render(request, "_frm_inner_form.html", data)
```

and urls

```
url(r'^measures/form/add/$', add_measure_form, name="add_measure_form")
```

Comment: like this `$("#append_forms").load(url);` maybe?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I think that load() replaces the contents of the div, that is why I added after(). But still I am wrong...

Comment: Sorry, no. It's just doesn't load() another time. No console errors, no http errors so far.

Comment: when you click on the button, does it get inside `function addForm(url){` everytime?

Comment: @Maximus. Yes. I checked with "console.info()".

Comment: @xpanta, can you setup a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the after() function append a wrapper div to the forms and load the data into it:

```
 function addForm(url){
   $("#append_forms").append('<div>').load(url);
  }
```

or use the general ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  url:url,
  success:function(data) { 
       $("#append_forms").append(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am sorry, it didn't work. I tried this with append and prepend.

Comment: is the ajax successful, has the returned html  head+body tags in it?

Comment: yes. For the moment I just return '<p>hi!</p>'. First time loads, second time although it doesn't.

Comment: does the general ajax request my  answer above work?

Comment: $.load empties the element and then adds the html so you where just overriding  the text each time you do a ajax call